# Identifying Android methods list which requires dangers permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to identify all the android methods which need to have `dangers permissions` before calling the methods. As an example, the permission READ_CALENDAR should be granted before using the method `Camera.open()`

Is there any please which I can obtain all the such methods which require permissions?

Comment: You want a list of Dangerous Permission in the document or you want to put them all in the same place in your code? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: I need to have a list of methods (and classes) which requires  dangers permissions

Comment: That is not strictly possible.

First, the answer will vary by Android OS version and possibly even by device model, if the manufacturer has made modifications to Android, both in terms of what the permissions are and what is defended by those permissions.

Second, there is no defined list of `dangerous` permissions, as apps can define new `dangerous` permissions.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can see the list of such dangers permission list in following location https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous
In addition to above - If there is no such defined list, How the developers know whether a particular method requires permission before using it?

Comment: Sometimes, the JavaDocs say whether a given method is known to require a permission. But, in general, you do not know until you use the method, run your test case, and get the `SecurityException`.

Comment: @CommonsWare The basic question is, if you refer the link [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) How do I know the method `insertDummyContact()` requires  the permision `WRITE_CONTACTS` ?

Comment: @ShaAk: You call it and crash with a `SecurityException`, most likely. That method is not part of the Android SDK and is undocumented outside of the context of that blog post. Even the Android SDK documentation will not cover this, as there is no way for anyone to know what permissions, if any, are required for any particular `ContentProviderOperation`. What is deciding if a permission is required is the actual `ContentProvider`, and it can do that statically in the manifest or dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Could you please  describes the characteristics of such method which requires system permission. As I understood from your comment, such methods will throw SecurityException. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PScout as a tool to get the list of methods up to SDK version 23. Use the below like for the resource. 
http://pscout.csl.toronto.edu/